# Google Background Location Acccess Disclouser

Tags: background, location, new-operator, policy

I am working on a Task which need to Access Users Location on Every 5 Minutes even when the App is Killes or Closed.

I have Already Achived it. But google play console Restricted me with the below message.

Prominent disclosure not found
Your app must display a prominent disclosure through a pop-up alert before your app’s location runtime permission. Based on our review, a prominent disclosure did not appear before the runtime permission.

Please add a prominent disclosure before the runtime permission.

•   Include at least the following sentence, adapted to include all the relevant features requesting access to location in the background in the app that are readily visible to the user: ****“This app collects location data to enable ["feature"], ["feature"], & ["feature"] even when the app is closed or not in use.” If you extend permitted usage to ads, please also include: “This data is also used to provide ads/support advertising/support ads.”****
•   Include any other details necessary to make it clear to the user how and why you are using location in the background. While additional content is permitted, it should not cause the required content to not be immediately visible.

I have also Added Pop Up, But i am Confused about, Should i Show that Pop Up Every Time On Accessing Location Or Only Once when App Being Installed,

Any help or Lead will be Appreaciated , (Respect)

Rajat.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some Resaerch work on my Question, I have found a Answer for this Question.

We dont need to to show pop-up everytime on accessing location  from background.
This popup will shown only once in a app maybe in HomeScreen after app install first time.

[Proof of Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sRBF.png)

Answer (score 0):

In genrealy, you pop-up dialog should appear before your app’s location runtime permission including

> Include at least the following sentence, adapted to include all the
> relevant features requesting access to location in the background in
> the app that are readily visible to the user: “This app collects
> location data to enable ["feature"], ["feature"], & ["feature"] even
> when the app is closed or not in use.” Include any other details
> necessary to make it clear to the user how and why you are using
> location in the background. While additional content is permitted, it
> should not cause the required content to not be immediately visible.
> Include the following sentence, if you extend permitted usage to ads:
> “This data is also used to provide ads.”